# Add more ram in HP Laptop 15-bs0xx?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, cpu, performance

Laptop Model-HP Laptop 15-bs0xx
Board: HP 832A 23.70
Processor: 2.30 gigahertz Intel Core i3-7020U
Architecture: 64 bit
OS: Windows 10 home
Slot1 = 4GB RAM (Speed- 2400 MHz, Form Factor- SODIMM
Slot2 = Empty

So what amount of ram should i add in slot 2 with what specifications?
Or can i change ram in both slots, if yes then what amount of ram should i add so that my processor and my laptop gives best performance without damage or excessive heat.

Comment: IMO: i would grab another 1 x 4GB RAM (Speed- 2400 MHz, Form Factor- SODIMM) and use that in slot 2, upgrading to 16GB on a 2 core CPU would be overkill but it does all come down to what youre using the laptop for.

Comment: What is overkill in 16Gb on a 2core CPU means?Will it work or not?

Comment: I don’t see you ever using your 16gbs of ram as you will always been CPU bottlenecked check out the answer from gronostaj this is explained there and the best answer

Comment: Just a question please, will two 8gb Ram work in my processor or will it be damaging?

Comment: Read gronostajs answer he gave you the answers there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add more RAM into the 2nd slot. Replacing currently installed module is also possible.

Here's an excerpt from HP's [maintenance manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05493257) for this laptop (p. 2-3):

[image: Screenshot from the manual, textual form available below]

> **Memory**
>
> **Two non-customer-accessible/upgradable memory module slots (Intel Core processors)**
>
> DDR4-2133 dual channel support (6th and 7th generation Intel Core processors)
>
> DDR4-2400 dual channel support (5th and 8th generation Intel Core processors)
>
> Supports up to 16 GB of system RAM in the following configurations:
>
> - 16384-MB total system memory (8192×2)
> - 12288-MB total system memory (8192×1) + (4096×1)
> - 8192-MB total system memory (8192×1) or (4096×2)
> - 6144-MB total system memory (4096×1) + (2048×1)
> - 4096-MB total system memory (4096×1)

Modules faster than 2400 MHz are not officially supported. They may work, but they'll most likely underclock to 2400 MHz, so don't pay extra for them.

Faster modules will always underclock to max common supported speed. So for example if you have a 2133 MHz + 2400 MHz pair, both modules will run at 2133 MHz. So try to get a 2400 MHz module, otherwise the current one will run slower too.

Running two modules of the same capacity will give you additional performance gain, because dual channel will be utilized.

8+8 GB is the most powerful configuration that will work in this laptop.

4 GB is definitely not enough nowadays, but buying a new 8+8 kit probably doesn't make sense for this laptop. Adding additional 4 GB 2400 MHz module should give you a significant performance gain. For regular day-to-day use I wouldn't recommend more than 8 GB because you'll be limited by the CPU anyway.

Comment: What does this means "For regular day-to-day use I wouldn't recommend more than 8 GB because you'll be limited by the CPU anyway." ?

Comment: Once you upgrade to 8 GB total, CPU will become the bottleneck. Performance gains from adding more memory will most likely not be worth it because your computer won't be significantly limited by scarcity of RAM anymore. Upgrading the CPU in these laptops is not possible, so my recommendation is to stick to 8 GB RAM total, maybe 12 GB tops if your workload is RAM-heavy. The next reasonable upgrade would be to replace the laptop. IMO you can't squeeze more out of this one by going for 16 GB.

Comment: @gronostaj That might not be good advise. The 16GB upgrade in the same laptop has definitely made a difference for me. Lowering the swappiness parameter, caching firefox to ram, moving /tmp to ram and some other tweaks, turned my crappy, entry-level HP into a moderately decent video editing tool for home projects. This might not be meaningful for the average Joe  or the grandma who merely checks email and youtube, but the OP is clearly wanting to tweak his laptop, so (s)he is (at least on the path of becoming) above that average user.

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop takes DDR4 RAM. So when purchasing, make sure you buy DDR4.

The maximum your laptop can take is 8GB in each slot, totaling 16GB.

Please see [this](https://www.memorycow.co.uk/laptop/hp/15-bs-series/hp-15-bs0xx-intel-core-i-series2-slotsddr4-laptop) link. It shows compatible RAM for your laptop make and model.

Comment: This question may sound silly but i have to ask that can i trust this site https://www.memorycow.co.uk/ for compatibility ? Have you used it ?

Comment: Memorycow is trusted. I merely used the link to show compatible RAM for comparison. Where you decide to purchase your RAM is for you to decide and is not a matter for Super User.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05493257), your laptop supports up to 16GB RAM so you can buy 2x8GB modules. But the manual is for multiple models so check if your model has DDR3L or DDR4 modules.